# Query resolved dependency version in yarn workspaces-project

Tags: dependencies, yarnpkg, dependency-management, monorepo, hoisting

I'm working on a project that is set up to use yarn workspaces. We use different versions of certain dependencies in the different workspaces. Other workspaces use those dependencies, but don't have them specified in their `package.json`.

yarn applies the concept of hoisting all dependencies to the root workspace. This way all workspaces have access to all dependencies that exist in the project.

However, for the workspaces that use dependencies, that aren't specified in the package.json, its not clear which version those workspaces are actually resolving.

How can I query the resolved version of a specific dependency per workspace?